# How to execute setenv command inside ruby code

Tags: ruby

I am trying to set an environmental variable inside the ruby code by below mentioned 3 methods. Like this:

```
one = `setenv HEMANT2 \"hi\"`

two = %x[ export HEMANT2=hi1]

there = system("setenv HEMANT \"hi\"")
```

And none of these 3 seems to be working. I am working on tcsh. Wondering what did I miss?

Comment: Are you trying to write a Ruby program which will change your own environment in your shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables belong to a process and are passed to their children. All of your lines above create a child shell process. The environment variable is changed in the child shell process, not its parent Ruby process.

Instead, use the [`ENV` class](https://ruby-doc.org/core/ENV.html).

```
ENV['HEMANT2'] = 'hi'
```

---

This will set the `HEMANT2` environment variable in your Ruby process. But it will not change the environment variables in your shell.

```
$ cat ~/tmp/test.rb
ENV['HEMANT2'] = 'hi'
$ ruby ~/tmp/test.rb
$ echo $HEMANT2

$
```

Again, because environment variables belong to a process and are inherited by their children. `ruby ~/tmp/test.rb` forks a child process of your shell. It cannot set its parent's environment variables.

---

You can do it with a shell script, *but only if you `source` it*. `source` does not create a child process, it runs the commands in your shell.

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh

HEMANT2=hi

$ sh test.sh
$ echo $HEMANT2

$ source test.sh
$ echo $HEMANT2
hi
```

This *only* works with shell scripts written for your shell.

Comment: Aah. I see your point. Thanks for the clarification. Cheers!